# How to support multiple extensions in Deft?

Tags: files, deft-mode

In [deft mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/deft/) I can change the default text extension using

```
(setq deft-extension "txt")
```

Is there any way to support multiple file types? (e.g. I have a mix of .txt .md and .org files in my directory)

Comment: Could you link to deft-mode?

Comment: oh sorry: it's this one http://jblevins.org/projects/deft/

Comment: The short answer is no, deft only supports a single file extension at the moment. It would need to be updated. What about creating new notes, would you still want a single extension used as the default? One of the goals of deft is not to think about file names / extensions, I believe.

Comment: I see that it is more difficult than a simple regexp as I was hoping. I like the way [nvALT](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/) handles file extensions: several are recognized, and one is specified as a default for new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the workaround in @ws6079's answer, you can use advice to specify a default extension for new files.

Here's an example that defaults to `txt` (using Emacs 24.4-style advice):

```
(setq deft-extension "")
(defvar deft-default-extension "txt")

(defun my/deft-default-extension (orig-func &rest args)
  (let ((deft-extension deft-default-extension))
    (apply orig-func args)))

(when (not (version< emacs-version "24.4"))         
  (advice-add 'deft-new-file :around #'my/deft-default-extension))
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @glucas this does not seem to be possible right now. A somewhat acceptable workaround for multiple file types is (for me) to set

```
(setq deft-extension "")
```

which matches all files in the directory. Unfortunately new files then have an dot extension `.` e.g., `todo_test.`.

Comment: To deal with the new file issue, maybe you could advise `deft-new-file-named` and use `let` to set the extension for the duration of that call?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty big bump, but it really can be just a simple regexp as you (@ws6079) suggested in a comment. The following works for `.org` and `.txt` files:

`(setq deft-extension "\\(\\.org\\'\\|\\.txt\\'\\)")`

I don't know if support for this had been added since you first asked.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that still doesn't seem to work properly for my version. Specifically, the names of newly created file names are messed up.

Answer (score 0):

From the file deft.el, this works

```
(setq deft-extensions '("txt" "tex" "org")
```